# Cant connect to my Windows PC from my MAC Laptop

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, printer

I shared an HP printer from my Windows 7 PC however when I try to connect my Mac laptop to the printer it always asks for a username and password. When I input my username and password my Mac rejects them and won't connect to my printer.

The username and password I am entering are as follows:

> `Username: DM`
>
> `Password: 12345`

I also tried to connect it as a **Guest** user but this doesn't work either.

How can I fix this?

**Error message**

```
\\192.168.254.3 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. 

Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft you must first enable the LDP Print Service by using the `Turn Windows features on or off` within `Programs and Features`:

> **First**, Enable the LDP Print Service using the following steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, and click **Control panel**
> 2. Click **Programs** and then click **Programs and Features**
> 3. Click **Turn Windows Features on or off**
> 4. Click to expand **Print and Document Services**
> 5. Check the box for **LDP Print Services**
> 6. Click **OK** and close the **Programs and Features** window
>
> **Next**, share the Windows printer on the network using the following
>   steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, type **Devices and Printers** in the Search text box
> 2. Click **Devices and Printers** from the list above
> 3. Right-click on the printer to be shared and click **Printer properties**
> 4. Click the **Sharing** tab and click **Change Sharing Options**
> 5. Check the box to Share this printer
> 6. Set the name for the share (**Note**: use a share name with no spaces, **Example**: Windows_HP_Printer)
> 7. Click **OK** and then close the **Properties** and **Devices and Printers** windows

(Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2665700)

If your Mac asks for a username and password whilst connecting to the shared printer follow these additional steps:

1. In Windows run `cmd.exe` (command prompt)
2. Type `hostname` into the command prompt window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Note the Windows computer name that is displayed from running `hostname`
4. In the Mac username/password box type the computer name you noted earlier, followed by a back slash (`\`) and then your Windows username into the `Username` box (and then your Windows user password into the `Password` box). E.g.

> `Username: HP-PC-123\BigChris
>    Password: **********`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the procedure written in this [HP Support](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04510394)?

If not then try it and let us know.

**Note**: Do not put your password here.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Please see the updated question.